# Yosemite MAMP regret

Tags: mysql, mamp, osx-yosemite

I made a really big mistake.

So I'm running OS X Yosemite latest with MAMP.

I accidentally deleted the mysql.pid file in MAMP/tmp/mysql/ by mistake because I read in another article that it would fix it. Turns out it didn't.

However I did fix another issue regarding the Apache Server which was adding a "_" on a certain file. So my Apache server has the green light.

But MYSQLServer just won't turn on the green light. Before deleting that file, it was turning on. Ugh.

So I thought maybe I uninstall MAMP by deleting the MAMP folder and putting it into trash and deleting it forever. Oops.

Now when I reinstalled MAMP, it actually remembered my old MAMP that I "thought" I "deleted" and uninstalled.

So now I get a message that says: 
Apache couldn't be started because port 8888 is in use by some other software

So I'm really screwed and not sure what to do after. Really sorry with this.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Using Activity Monitor search for: MySqld and Httpd and end the process for them. I had one Mysqld and loads of Httpd. After this restart Mamp and fingers crossed you'll get both green lights..

Answer (score 0):

Go to your MAMP directory. Go to Library/bin there is a file called envvars change the name to _envvars.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded MAMP from version 1.9.6 to 3.0.7.2 (on OS X Yosemite) and got the same error:

> Apache couldn't be started because port 8888 is in use by some other software.

I tried:

- deleting MAMP and reinstalling
- stopping any httpd and mysqld processes then restarting MAMP
- changing the port

...and a few other things suggested in Stack Overflow answers with no success.

In the end I fixed the issue by deleting MAMP, restarting my machine and then installing MAMP again.